# LINQ expression could not be translated in simple query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Hello and thanks for your help.  I have a connection to an SQL table, the table contains a field called "company" which is the name of the company.  What I'm trying to do is, I have an array of words (or list with the words I would like to search, for example:

```
List<string> WordsToSearch = new List<string>() { "shabab", "motor", "sales" };
```

Now, I would like to search in my table, all the accounts that have all these words in their name, so I proceeded like this:

```
var search = await mydb.Accounts.Where(w => WordsToSearch.All( w.Company.Contains ) ).ToListAsync();
```

but what I get is an error as follow:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Account>
.Where(a => __palabras_0
    .All((Func<string, bool>)(MethodInfo)Boolean Contains(System.String).CreateDelegate(
        delegateType: (Type)System.Func`2[System.String,System.Boolean], 
        target: a.Company)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

Now, if I do a change, I can get this to work as follow:

```
var search = await mydb.Accounts.ToListAsync(); 
var test = search.Where(w => WordsToSearch.All( w.Company.Contains ) );
```

The result is ok, would you please tell me why am I getting this error? or what am I doing wrong? THANK YOU very much for your help!

Comment: Your error message is pretty self-explanatory

Comment: have you tried : `mydb.Accounts.Where(w => WordsToSearch.Contains (w.Company)).ToListAsync();` or ``mydb.Accounts.Where(w => WordsToSearch.Any(x=> x == w.Company)).ToListAsync();``

Comment: `var search = await mydb.Accounts.Where(a => WordsToSearch.All( w => a.Company.Contains(w) ) ).ToListAsync();`
might also work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that your request has a conditional search that can not be directly expressed in a SQL language (or server side). The data should be fetched to an enumerable object (like a list) and even asynchronously and the condition should be evaluated in the client side (your program). Be aware of performance issues you will face because there is no acceleration by indexing or any help from database.